# Editor (Sublime, Notepad++, etc.) Paste 'around' existing text

Tags: python, editor, notepad++, sublimetext3, spyder

**Motivation:** I was going around assigning parameters read in from a config file to variables in a function like so:

```
john = my_quest
terry = my_fav_color
eric = airspeed
ni = swallow_type
...
```

when I realized this was going to be a lot of parameters to pass. I thus decided I'd put these parameters in a nice dictionary, `grail`, e.g. `grail['my_quest']` so that the only thing I needed to pass to the function was `grail`.

**Question:**  Is there a simple way in Sublime (or Notepad++, Spyder, Pycharm, etc.) to paste `grails['`variable`']` around those variables in one step, instead of needing to paste the front and back seperately? (I know about multiple cursors in Sublime, that does help, but I'd love to find a "highlight-variable-and-hit-`ctrl-meta-shift-\`" and it's done.)

Comment: Mayeb take a look at vim and the `surround.vim` plugin.

Comment: in `vim`, `%s/= \(\w*\)$/= grails['\1']/gc`

Comment: I've had some very traumatic experiences with emacs recently, and vi tends to trigger the same response (he bravely ran away).  Having said that, `surround.vim` looks quite interesting.  Is there an equivalent in any of the easier - I mean less powerful - editors?

Comment: @schodge For ST, https://github.com/jcartledge/sublime-surround. Unsure how feature complete it is, but may be worth a look.

Comment: @schodge - if I can recommend, I would prefer learning regular expressions before using of single-purpose plugins. From long-term view it pays much more - you learn it once (at least the basics) and then you use it with many applications for searches or replacements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on examples you provided, this is a simple task solvable using standard regex find/replace.

So in Notepad++, record this macro (for recording control examine **Macro** menu):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd> to open **Find/Replace** dialog
2. Find what: `= (.*)$`
3. Replace with: `= grail['\1']`
4. Choose **Regular Expression** and press **Replace All**

If you finish recording the macro and you choose to save it, shortcut key is requested. Assign your favorite <kbd>ctrl-meta-shift-\</kbd> and you are done.

Comment: for your convenience:   in "Find What": `.`=any character, `*`=repeat previous character 0..N times (take maximum), `$`=end of line, `()` create first group from text inside it (from now, it is referred as `\1`), so you can use this group in "Replace with"